# How to query the Google Analytics Data API (GA4) using an event_category and an event_label?

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-data-api

I'm using .NET 5 and the nuget package Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta to query Google Analytics. But I need to query events using the event_category and the event_label and I get this error: "Field customEvent:event_category is not a valid dimension". This is my code:

```
            var click = new FilterExpression
            {
                Filter = new Filter
                {
                    FieldName = "ga:event_category",
                    StringFilter = new Filter.Types.StringFilter
                    {
                        CaseSensitive = false,
                        MatchType = Filter.Types.StringFilter.Types.MatchType.Exact,
                        Value = "click"
                    }
                },
            };
            var request = new RunReportRequest
            {
                Property = $"properties/{_settings.GoogleAnalytics.PropertyId}",
                Dimensions = {new Dimension {Name = "eventName"}, new Dimension {Name = "customEvent:event_category" } },
                DimensionFilter = click,
                Metrics = {new Metric {Name = "eventCount"}},
                DateRanges =
                {
                    new DateRange
                        {StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), EndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
                }
            };

            var response = await _analyticsClient.GetClient().RunReportAsync(request);
```

How do I pass event_category and event_label to the query?

Comment: event_category & event_label need to be registered custom definitions to be passed in the query. [This guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced#event-scoped_custom_dimensions) describes verifying that you have registered the event parameters as custom definitions.